Using += in Java ternary expression
I am trying to use a generic type with a ternary expression to execute expressions that do not return a value. Here is my class:
  static class Generic<T> {
    T t;
  }

  public static Generic generic = new Generic();

I am executing a simple command. The Java compiler does not produce any errors for my_a += 1, yet it disallows my_b += 1.
generic.t = X ? my_a += 1 : my_b += 1;

My question is: why doesn't it allow the second expression?
This is mostly an experimental piece of code. I am just trying to understand the way ternary works in Java and why can't I use += in my_b += 1 .
code:
bool X = true;
int my_a = 0;
int my_b = 0;
generic.t = X ? my_a += 1 : my_b += 1;

Exception:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
        Syntax error on token "+=", + expected

Changing my_b += 1; to my_b++ compiles and executes the code successfully. I expected the code will execute with my_b += 1; since a generic type is designed to be compatible with various data types.

You haven't shown us anything about my_a or my_b, and you appear to be creating an instance of the raw type of Generic. Without a [mcve] it's hard to reproduce the problem ourselves, or suggest a change. (I would personally start by removing any generic aspects here. It's hard to see how my_a += 1 would return something compatible with T, in general...)

What are the types of my_a and my_b ?

you want "to understand the way ternary works", but are mixing Generics and compound assignment with a ternary operator... kind of courageous... anyway, best include a [mre] in the question

public static Generic generic = new Generic(); - you're using a raw type which is best avoided. You should specify e.g. public static Generic<Integer> generic = new Generic<>();

Also, you say "expressions that do not return a value". Actually, my_b += 1 does return a value; it's the same as ++my_b which is an int. For example, you can do int my_c = (my_b += 1);

The operator precedence rules are wonky here. You need parentheses. This works fine:
generic.t = X ? (my_a += 1) : (my_b += 1);

